# How to format printf output

Tags: c, printf

I have a for loop that prints out data from an array but I want them to print out so that they all line up neatly.

```
1.  123124124 24
2.  12412452  56
3.  12312     12
.
.
.
10. 12412412  12
```

I have `printf("%d.%d%d\n", x, y, z)`; Any help is appreciated!

Comment: something like `printf("%-*s%-9d%3d\n", 4-printf("%d", x), ".", y, z);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printf("%-3d%-12d%d\n", x, y, z);
```

The number following the minus sign and preceeding the d is the minimum width of the field. For the count column, we want it to be at least 3 columns wide. However, we also want it to pad to the right, which is why the minus sign is used.

Same goes for the %-12d, except that the minimum width is 12. Have a look at this sample

http://codepad.org/jJA8v8v8

If you want the period, you're going to have to print that as a string with %s.

Comment: Is it possible to show how it would look like to have the period?

Comment: `printf("%-3d%s%-12d%d\n", x, ".", y, z);` @JMei

Comment: @JMei Your suggested `printf()` can have spaces between `x` and `"."`  That differs from `"1.  123124124 24"`.

Answer (score 1):

OP's requested format is challenging as it wants a `'.'` immediately following the `(int) x` and then padded as needed.

[@BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39541765/how-to-format-printf-output#comment66397449_39541765), as usual, offers a nifty solution.  This takes advantage of the result of first printing `x`.

```
printf("%-*s%-9d%3d\n", 4-printf("%d", x), ".", y, z);
```

Alternative, convert to `double`.

`"%-#3.0f` Prints `double`, at least 3 characters, left justified, always with `'.'`, no digits after the `'.'`.

```
//123 123456789 12
//10. 12412412  12
//1.  123124124 24
printf("%-#3.0f %-9d %d\n", (double) x, y, z);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%d. \t %d \t %d \n", x, y, z);
```

\t inserts a tab, which should align your code nicely.

Comment: Haha, I guess you're right. But they will align them into columns.

Answer (score 0):

use `%-numd` or `%numd` to control the output style.
The `num` means the width you want to have. Replace it by numbers, like: `%-10d` or `%10d`. 
 And `-` means left aligned. Without it, the output will be right aligned.
For examle: `printf("%-5d%5d",123,456)` then the output will be `123    456`

Comment: The brackets (parentheses) in your first line are at best confusing.  They aren't a valid part of a `printf` conversion specification.